# Как сделать свой android браузер для HTML5 игр?

Tags: android, html5, разработка-игр

Сделал простой браузер как в этом уроке - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/72-urok-32-pishem-prostoj-brauzer.html - обычные страницы (ya.ru) в нём грузятся и прекрасно работают, а html5 игры не хотят полностью грузиться.
В MainActivity в качестве ссылки вместо http://www.ya.ru передаю https://play.famobi.com/fruita-crush/ или https://www.snappygames.com/ru/game/tiny-defense.aspx.

Сначала появляется такой экран - [image: начальный экран]
Потом такой (так и остаётся) - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ссылку (https://play.famobi.com/fruita-crush/ или https://www.snappygames.com/ru/game/tiny-defense.aspx) открываю в Chrome или Opera, то всё ок - можно играть.

Что я сделал не правильно? Есть ли возможность запуска сторонних html5 игр в своём браузере?

PS: я смотрел в сторону PhoneGap (и ему подобных), но, судя по описанию на вики, он мне поможет сконвертировать JavaScript-HTML5-CSS3 приложение в нативное приложение (под разные мобильные платформы). Но мне надо не конвертировать разные приложения в нативные, а запускать их в браузере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте включить поддержку javascript. В указанном Вами уроке про js ничего не написано. Включить ее можно так:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: спасибо, это решило вопрос.В логе приложения я увидел строчку `W/cr_CrashFileManager: ... Reports does not exist or is not a directory` и нашёл решение здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592026/my-application-keeps-on-crashing